# Regex quantifier more than one group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex to get a sequence of number 1 followed by number 0 and the total numbers should be equal to a max length. Is there a way to do something like `(([1]+)([0]+)){maxLength}` ?

Ex.:
maxLength = 7

```
10 -> should not pass (total length < maxLength)
1111100 -> should match
1000000 -> should match
11110000000 -> should match 1111000.
111111111111 -> should match 1111111.
```

Plus: The sequence could be 0 followed by 1, and the greater the amount of 1 the better (I don't know if it's possible in only one regex).
000000001111 -> should get 0001111.

I'm focusing on 1 followed by 0.

I started with `[1]+[0]+`,
after I quantified the 0s `([1]+)([0]{1,7})`,
but it still giving more 0s than I want.

Then I was thinking in `([1]{7,}|[1]{6}[0]{1}|[1]{5}[0]{2}|[1]{4}[0]{3}|[1]{3}[0]{4}|[1]{2}[0]{5}|[1]{1}[0]{6})`,
and ok, it works. BUT if maxLength = 100 the above solution is not viable.

Is there some way to count the length of the first matched group and then the second group to be the difference from the first one?

Or something like `(([1]+)([0]+)){7}` ?

Comment: And what about `000011110000`? What do you want to match here?

Comment: @JvdV Should match 1111000 (greater the amount of 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want:

```
^(?:(?=1+0*$)|(?=0+1*$))[01]{7}
```

Here the `{7}` can be replaced with whatever the max length is minus one.

Comment: This doesn't match 0001111 in 000000001111  though?

Comment: @JvdV True, I can do another regex with sequence starting by 0: (?=0+1*$)[01]{7}, but when I put 000011110000 the expected response should be 0001111 - and the regex is not matching.

Comment: That does not match your comment underneath your question when I asked about this specific case.

Comment: @JvdV Should match 0001111 or 1111000, the important thing is the max quantity of numbers one. Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt using branch reset group:

```
0*(?|(1[10]{6})|([10]{6}1))
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8m7Ku6/1). You can use the result from 1st capture group.

- `0*` - 0+ literal zeros (greedy) upto;
- `(?|` - Open branch reset group:

  - `(1[10]{6})` - 1st Capture group holding a literal 1 and 6 ones or zeros.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `([10]{6}1)` - 1st Capture group holding 6 ones or zeros upto and a literal one.
  - `)` - Close branch reset group.

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex can be as simple as:

```
/0*([01]{7})/
```

---

example:

```js
const result = `
10
1111100
1000000
11110000000
111111111111
000000001111
`.split("\n").reduce((acc, str) => {
  const m = str.match(/0*([01]{7})/);
  m && acc.push(m[1]);
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(result)
```